# How can I navigate to tcl proc body in notepad++ by clicking on the call of the procedure

Tags: tcl, notepad++, proc

In Visual studio I can navigate to C++ function body by clicking on the name of the function(call of the function) while pressing "ctrl" key button.
How can I do the same for tcl "proc"s in notepad++ ?

Answer (score 1):

NP++ provides very basic support for Tcl/Tk development. Try Geany which has most of required features according to https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Tcl+Editors, and the code management is among them.

In [Geany](https://www.geany.org), Ctrl+clicking a proc/method name would very likely find its declaration, scanning the current session's open files. Also, View/Side bar/Symbols shows all of the declarations.